# Google Play и "зачем вам фоновое определение местоположения?"

Tags: android, google-play, gps

Есть проект, опубликованный в Google Play. Это онлайн карта с функциями определения местоположения по GPS и сотовым вышкам.

Сегодня увидел, что мне надо ответить на ряд вопросов, связанных с "зачем мне определение местоположения (в том числе и фоновое)?"

#1

> Использует ли ваше приложение разрешение на доступ к данным о местоположении в фоновом режиме в APK-файлах или наборах App Bundle, созданных для Android 9 (Pie) или более ранних версий (SDK 28 или более ранней версии)? Подробнее...

> Нет
> Если ваше приложение будет осуществлять доступ к данным о местоположении в фоновом режиме, оно может быть удалено из Google Play.

> Да
> Предоставьте дополнительную информацию ниже.

Тут, конечно же, отвечаю "да". Ведь это так и есть.

#2

> Соответствует ли ваше приложение правилам использования разрешений на доступ к данным о местоположении?

> Да, это приложение соответствует правилам использования разрешений на доступ к данным о местоположении

> Нет, это приложение не соответствует правилам использования разрешений на доступ к данным о местоположении
> Вы можете отправить эту форму, не заполняя ее дальше. Если приложение не будет соответствовать нашим правилам, мы можем удалить его из Google Play.

Вот тут становится непонятно "что делать мне дальше?".
Что будет, если я отвечу "нет, не соответствует"?
Если нажму "да, соответствует", то вылазят формы для заполнения:

#3

> Каково основное назначение приложения?

> Данные о местоположении
> Зачем вашему приложению требуется доступ к данным о местоположении в фоновом режиме? Подробнее...
> Расскажите об одной функции приложения, требующей доступа к данным о местоположении в фоновом режиме, и объясните, почему без этих данных она не может работать. Функция должна быть связана с основным назначением приложения. Разрешение предоставляется для всего приложения, а не для конкретной функции.

> Видеоинструкции
> Предоставьте ссылку на короткое видео, в котором демонстрируется описанная вами функция. Подробнее...
> http://
> Видео должно содержать заметное уведомление, которое сообщает пользователям о том, что приложение имеет доступ к данным о местоположении. Рекомендованная продолжительность видео – не больше 30 секунд.

Без загруженного видео он не хочет принимать текстовые ответы.
Собственно мой вопрос "что мне делать?".
Нажать "да или нет" в вопросе "соответствие требованиям"?
Если "да", то что именно ответить и какое видео надо загрузить? А то я наслышан о злой поддержке Гугла и не хочется ошибаться с ними.

Мои разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Судя по описанию приложения - вам функция фонового определения местоположения не нужна. Коли так - наверное можно выпустить апдейт с убиранием разрешения и этого функционала. Возможно, гугл увидит, что разрешения больше нет и всё само собой уладится, а может гугл проигнорирует изменения и забанит приложение и аккаунт за нарушение, тут уж как повезёт. Если фоновое определение местоположения действительно используется (например для виждета с картой или для чего-то типа автонавигатора) - снимите видео про это

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а вы не знаете, это видео будет использовано саппортом гугла или оно будет так же показано ВСЕМ пользователем? от этого зависит "какое видиео снимать" - просто захват экрана или заморочиться и сделать красивое? p.s. я не хочу чтобы забанили акк и приложение))

Comment: Юзерам показывать не должны. Это должна быть, по идее, простая демонстрация того, что описанное вами на словах в приложении присутствует и это не надо проверяющим выискивать в незнакомом приложении. Про баны - вас ничто не защитит и предохраниться невозможно. В любой момент вас может забанить робот по любой причине. Тут ничего сделать нельзя, можно только смириться.